# How to add JSON data directly into MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert API JSON data inside MongoDB database using mongoose.
Instead of using `db.collectionname.insert(my-data)` in Mongo shell is there any smart way to insert JSON data directly into database from API url eg:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_INTRADAY&symbol=BTC&market=CNY&apikey=demo

I want to add JSON from API url directly into my MongoDB database and on interval of 5min it should again add data from API url and delete the previous one.

API JSON consists of around 100 objects time-series data.

```
         "2018-01-17 15:10:00": {
            "1a. price (CNY)": "75534.79209000",
            "1b. price (USD)": "11738.59636399",
            "2. volume": "0.02374000",
            "3. market cap (USD)": "278.67427768"
        },
        "2018-01-17 15:05:00": {
            "1a. price (CNY)": "75534.79209000",
            "1b. price (USD)": "11738.59636399",
            "2. volume": "0.02374000",
            "3. market cap (USD)": "278.67427768"
        }
```

Comment: you can write a simple `bash` script to `wget` json to local system and use `mongoimport` with option `--drop` to wipe existing and load fresh data

Comment: @Saravana Can you please ellaborate I could not understand.

Comment: @Saravana How can I import json data from API URL directly into database instead of using `db.collectionname.insert(my-data)`

Comment: In which environment have you deployed the code? `Unix` or `Windows`?

Comment: @Saravana Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copy pasting data into mongo console we can directly use this command in CMD:

For csv file:

```
mongoimport --db databasename --collection collectionname --type csv --headerline --file filepath.csv
```